# Python Reportlab nested tables text reflow issue

Tags: python, nested, reportlab, reflow

I have a fairly complex multi-page report with flowables inside nested tables.  The report is now being used with much longer content than initially planned.  The report reflows fine with 3 nested tables, but when I add a fourth, it no longer reflows and crashes the script with this response:

`Flowable <Table@0x7FC7D4566200 1 rows x 3 cols(tallest row 1367)> with cell(0,1) containing '<Table@0x7FC7D4563638 3 rows x 4 cols(tallest row 1257)> with cell(0,1) containing\n\'<Table@0x7FC7D4556488 1 rows x 2 cols(tallest row 88)> with cell(0,0) containing\\n"<Table@0x7FC7D4561FC8 4 rows x 2 cols(tallest row 32)> with cell(0,0) containing\\\\n\\\'<Paragraph at 0x7fc7d45603f8>Classification\\\'"\''(612.0 x 1367), tallest cell 1367.0 points,  too large on page 5 in frame 'normal'(600.0 x 664.0*) of template 'normal'`

My current work-around plan is to do the following steps:

1. determine the page position before I place the content
2. get the length of the content
3. calculate the expected room remaining
4. calculate the space required for the content
5. if the content fits, add it to page, else:

   - split the content into 2 chunks (this can cause xml issues, though): chunkA and chunkB.
   - add chunkA to page
   - close table
   - start new table
   - process chunkB from step 1 above.

Clearly this process is fraught with issues.  Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: If you know that the 4th table will crash the program, why not make that the condition instead of checking the length of the content? Also, have you considered changing page size / orientation?

Comment: It's not the fourth table that crashes the program, it's content that needs to reflow from within a fourth table. I can't strip out a table without losing required graphics.
Each table has styles and framework that are required to make the report display properly.  It was the only way I could make the report look right.  For example, the outer table has a background color and defines margins for the content, with it's background color bleeding off the page to the left and right (I tried to do this type of layout other ways, but tables was the only reliable way).